# Cancel to previous function Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is shortcut to cancel to previous mouse position in editor?

I tried to use ctrl+- but I Have zoom in and out at this position.

What name could it have in shortcut listing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the "Navigate Forward" and "Navigate backward" commands available on the "View" menu. The menu will show the keys that are assigned to the commands.

Comment: This is VSCode and there are no navigate tabs in view

Comment: @JakubTroczyński The question clearly states Visual Studio. Neither the question title nor its body nor its tags refer to Visual Studio Code.